# Are there any synonyms/alternatives for the phrase "so much for (something)"?

Tags: phrase-request

I'm struggling to find any similar expressions to indicate my disappointment with a  subject or show that it's not true anymore.

Could someone provide any suchlike locutions, please?

Comment: Please show you effort first, such as a grammar tutorial, example sentences.

Comment: There are probably a ***lot*** of (both idiomatic *and* "plain language") ways of expressing much the same thing as *So much for [X]* in this sense. One that comes to mind is [***Bang goes (your theory)***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22bang+goes+your+theory%22) (said to someone whose theory has just been ***blown out of the water*** by some incontrovertible new evidence).

Comment: ...according to [Oxford Dictionary of English](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=anecAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=define+%22bang+goes%22+%22used+to+express+the+sudden+collapse+of+a+plan+or+hope%22&source=bl&ots=T_kxeqpGxP&sig=ACfU3U1fP3ziO8sSUrMRgeqS2d3crlXWqQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcw6-Ts6noAhUHJBoKHSkRAmMQ6AEwAXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=define%20%22bang%20goes%22%20%22used%20to%20express%20the%20sudden%20collapse%20of%20a%20plan%20or%20hope%22&f=false)), ***bang goes X*** is a specifically ***British*** idiom. Maybe there's some American near-equivalent alternative, I dunno.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example sentence with a blank where the phrase you are looking for should go.